# How to prove that the probability that a random graph has a stable set of size $2\lceil \log n\rceil$ is sub-constant?

Tags: graphs

Given a random graph on $n$ vertices where each edge is included with probability $1/2$. Lets call it $G=(n,1/2)$. How can we show that the probability that this graph has a stable set of size at least $2\lceil \log n\rceil$ is sub-constant?

Comment: I tihnk your question is not research-level, since such matters are the first to be investigated in the Erdos-Renyi model, which is what you are describing. I found some lecture [notes](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/462/2010/lect3-10.pdf), and they use the defining property of an independent set: no edges between any of the vertices.

Comment: If I recall both site policies correctly, you may re-post after a week if an answer was not given yourself, but you have to mention it is a cross-post and provide a link. I'll flag your question in case a moderator will move it automatically.

Comment: Why is this a question about computer science?  It sounds like a pure math question and thus not on-topic here.  Also, what is a "stable set"?  Please include a definition in your question.  Finally, what have you tried?  What research have you done?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question what you tried and what research you did.

Comment: @chazisop, no, that is not correct.  CSTheory has a special policy allowing cross-posts under the conditions you describe if the other site does, but CS.SE's policy does not allow that -- CS.SE follows standard Stack Exchange policy, which forbids cross-posting.

Comment: @D.W. I think graph theory is mostly accepted as part of TCS, isn't it?

Comment: Anyway, what have you tried and where did you get stuck? Don't just dump a question from whereever in the textbox.

Comment: I think the question is definitely on-topic, but it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that a specific set of size $k$ is a stable set is $2^{-\binom{k}{2}}$. Hence the probability that *some* set of size $k \leq n/2$ is stable is at most
$$
\binom{n}{k} 2^{-\binom{k}{2}} \leq 2\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k 2^{-k^2/2}.
$$
When $k = c\log n$ (logarithm to the base 2), this upper bound is
$$
2\left(\frac{en}{C\log n}\right)^{C\log n} 2^{-C^2\log^2 n/2}=
\frac{2^{(C-C^2/2)\log^2n}}{\Omega(\log n)^{\Omega(\log n)}} = o(2^{(C-C^2/2)\log^2n}).
$$
For $C \geq 2$, this is $o(1)$.